# android:How to copy smiley from grid and past on SMS and send with smiley image

Tags: android, android-layout, sms, paging, email-attachments

[image: I am try to implement Copy smileyand show on message]

- But how do i do this?

My requirement is that I have to open directly messaging/Email default android screen from my application and show in grid all images and selected image attch with sms/email and send.

- How to copy smiley from grid and past on SMS and send with smiley image.
- How to copy smiley from grid and past on Email and send with smiley image.
- Is it possible pagination in android gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - To Load Emoticon provide ArrayList(path of emoticons) to PagerAdpater



    private void loadEmoticons() {

            try {

                ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.emoticons_pager);

                ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (fileList != null) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < fileList.length; j++) {
                        paths.add(fileList[j]);
                    }

                }

                EmoticonsPagerAdapter adapter = new EmoticonsPagerAdapter(
                        EmailEmoticonsActivity.this, paths, this);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);

                mIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                mIndicator.setViewPager(pager);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

 1. select emoticon kkeyClickedIndex() it give selected emoticon Index.

       @Override
        public void keyClickedIndex(final int index, final String imagePath) {
            try {

                ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {

                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(
                                String.valueOf(index), ".");
                        d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                                emoticons[Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())]);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                d.getIntrinsicHeight());

                        return d;
                    }
                };

                Spanned cs = Html.fromHtml("<img src ='" + String.valueOf(index)
                        + "'/>", imageGetter, null);
                int cursorPosition = content.getSelectionStart();

                content.getText().insert(cursorPosition, cs);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }



 - Grid Adapter : pass image paths (arrayList) base on load all images
   on Grid view, KeyClickListener  interface use to get index of
   click/selected image.



    public class EmoticonsGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private ArrayList<String> paths;
        private int pageNumber;
        Context mContext;
        String urlImages[];
        KeyClickListener mListener;

        public EmoticonsGridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> paths,
                int pageNumber, KeyClickListener listener) {
            this.mContext = context;
            this.paths = paths;
            this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
            this.mListener = listener;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emoticons_item, null);
            }

            final String path = paths.get(position);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item);

            image.setImageBitmap(getImage(path));

            image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    mListener
                            .keyClickedIndex(
                                    (pageNumber * EmoticonsPagerAdapter.NO_OF_EMOTICONS_PER_PAGE)
                                            + position, path);
                }
            });
            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return paths.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return paths.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public int getPageNumber() {
            return pageNumber;
        }

        private Bitmap getImage(String path) {
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
            in = new FileInputStream(Constant.DIR + Constant.FILE_NAME
                        + File.separator + path);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, null);
            return temp;
        }
        public interface KeyClickListener {

        public void keyClickedIndex(int index, String imagePath);
            // public void keyClickedIndex(String indexImage);
        }
    }
 - Pager Emoticon

public class EmoticonsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> emoticons;
    public static final int NO_OF_EMOTICONS_PER_PAGE = 24;
    FragmentActivity mActivity;
    KeyClickListener mListener;

    public EmoticonsPagerAdapter(FragmentActivity activity,
            ArrayList<String> emoticons, KeyClickListener listener) {
        this.emoticons = emoticons;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int nubmer = (int) Math.ceil((double) emoticons.size()
                / (double) NO_OF_EMOTICONS_PER_PAGE);

        return nubmer;

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        View layout = mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.emoticons_grid, null);

        int initialPosition = position * NO_OF_EMOTICONS_PER_PAGE;
        ArrayList<String> emoticonsInAPage = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = initialPosition; i < initialPosition
                + NO_OF_EMOTICONS_PER_PAGE
                && i < emoticons.size(); i++) {
            emoticonsInAPage.add(emoticons.get(i));
        }

        GridView grid = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.emoticons_grid);
        EmoticonsGridAdapter adapter = new EmoticonsGridAdapter(
                mActivity.getApplicationContext(), emoticonsInAPage, position,
                mListener);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
}

 - Girdview layout (emoticons_grid.xml) Gridview to load image in pager

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/emoticons_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:numColumns="6"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />

 - item.xml signal item of gridview  

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/White" />

 - MainLayout add this to ViewPagerand CirclePageIndicator 

 <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/Gray"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:pageColor="#808080"
        app:radius="5dp"
        app:strokeColor="#000000"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/emoticons_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/Gray" />
```

- CirclePageIndicator

  public class CirclePageIndicator extends View implements PageIndicator {
      private static final int INVALID_POINTER = -1;

  ```
  private float mRadius;
  private final Paint mPaintPageFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  private final Paint mPaintStroke = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  private final Paint mPaintFill = new Paint(ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  private ViewPager mViewPager;
  private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mListener;
  private int mCurrentPage;
  private int mSnapPage;
  private float mPageOffset;
  private int mScrollState;
  private int mOrientation;
  private boolean mCentered;
  private boolean mSnap;

  private int mTouchSlop;
  private float mLastMotionX = -1;
  private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
  private boolean mIsDragging;

  public CirclePageIndicator(Context context) {
      this(context, null);
  }

  public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      this(context, attrs, R.attr.vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle);
  }

  public CirclePageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
      super(context, attrs, defStyle);
      if (isInEditMode())
          return;

      // Load defaults from resources
      final Resources res = getResources();
      final int defaultPageColor = res
              .getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_page_color);
      final int defaultFillColor = res
              .getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_fill_color);
      final int defaultOrientation = res
              .getInteger(R.integer.default_circle_indicator_orientation);
      final int defaultStrokeColor = res
              .getColor(R.color.default_circle_indicator_stroke_color);
      final float defaultStrokeWidth = res
              .getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_stroke_width);
      final float defaultRadius = res
              .getDimension(R.dimen.default_circle_indicator_radius);
      final boolean defaultCentered = res
              .getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_centered);
      final boolean defaultSnap = res
              .getBoolean(R.bool.default_circle_indicator_snap);

      // Retrieve styles attributes
      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
              R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator, defStyle, 0);

      mCentered = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_centered,
              defaultCentered);
      mOrientation = a.getInt(
              R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_android_orientation,
              defaultOrientation);
      mPaintPageFill.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      mPaintPageFill.setColor(a.getColor(
              R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_pageColor, defaultPageColor));
      mPaintStroke.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      mPaintStroke.setColor(a
              .getColor(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeColor,
                      defaultStrokeColor));
      mPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(a
              .getDimension(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_strokeWidth,
                      defaultStrokeWidth));
      mPaintFill.setStyle(Style.FILL);
      mPaintFill.setColor(a.getColor(
              R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_fillColor, defaultFillColor));
      mRadius = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_radius,
              defaultRadius);
      mSnap = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_snap, defaultSnap);

      Drawable background = a
              .getDrawable(R.styleable.CirclePageIndicator_android_background);
      if (background != null) {
          setBackgroundDrawable(background);
      }

      a.recycle();

      final ViewConfiguration configuration = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
      mTouchSlop = ViewConfigurationCompat
              .getScaledPagingTouchSlop(configuration);
  }

  public void setCentered(boolean centered) {
      mCentered = centered;
      invalidate();
  }

  public boolean isCentered() {
      return mCentered;
  }

  public void setPageColor(int pageColor) {
      mPaintPageFill.setColor(pageColor);
      invalidate();
  }

  public int getPageColor() {
      return mPaintPageFill.getColor();
  }

  public void setFillColor(int fillColor) {
      mPaintFill.setColor(fillColor);
      invalidate();
  }

  public int getFillColor() {
      return mPaintFill.getColor();
  }

  public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
      switch (orientation) {
      case HORIZONTAL:
      case VERTICAL:
          mOrientation = orientation;
          requestLayout();
          break;

      default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "Orientation must be either HORIZONTAL or VERTICAL.");
      }
  }

  public int getOrientation() {
      return mOrientation;
  }

  public void setStrokeColor(int strokeColor) {
      mPaintStroke.setColor(strokeColor);
      invalidate();
  }

  public int getStrokeColor() {
      return mPaintStroke.getColor();
  }

  public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
      mPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
      invalidate();
  }

  public float getStrokeWidth() {
      return mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth();
  }

  public void setRadius(float radius) {
      mRadius = radius;
      invalidate();
  }

  public float getRadius() {
      return mRadius;
  }

  public void setSnap(boolean snap) {
      mSnap = snap;
      invalidate();
  }

  public boolean isSnap() {
      return mSnap;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas);

      if (mViewPager == null) {
          return;
      }
      final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
      if (count == 0) {
          return;
      }

      if (mCurrentPage >= count) {
          setCurrentItem(count - 1);
          return;
      }

      int longSize;
      int longPaddingBefore;
      int longPaddingAfter;
      int shortPaddingBefore;
      if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
          longSize = getWidth();
          longPaddingBefore = getPaddingLeft();
          longPaddingAfter = getPaddingRight();
          shortPaddingBefore = getPaddingTop();
      } else {
          longSize = getHeight();
          longPaddingBefore = getPaddingTop();
          longPaddingAfter = getPaddingBottom();
          shortPaddingBefore = getPaddingLeft();
      }

      final float threeRadius = mRadius * 3;
      final float shortOffset = shortPaddingBefore + mRadius;
      float longOffset = longPaddingBefore + mRadius;
      if (mCentered) {
          longOffset += ((longSize - longPaddingBefore - longPaddingAfter) / 2.0f)
                  - ((count * threeRadius) / 2.0f);
      }

      float dX;
      float dY;

      float pageFillRadius = mRadius;
      if (mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth() > 0) {
          pageFillRadius -= mPaintStroke.getStrokeWidth() / 2.0f;
      }

      // Draw stroked circles
      for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < count; iLoop++) {
          float drawLong = longOffset + (iLoop * threeRadius);
          if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
              dX = drawLong;
              dY = shortOffset;
          } else {
              dX = shortOffset;
              dY = drawLong;
          }
          // Only paint fill if not completely transparent
          if (mPaintPageFill.getAlpha() > 0) {
              canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, pageFillRadius, mPaintPageFill);
          }

          // Only paint stroke if a stroke width was non-zero
          if (pageFillRadius != mRadius) {
              canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintStroke);
          }
      }

      // Draw the filled circle according to the current scroll
      float cx = (mSnap ? mSnapPage : mCurrentPage) * threeRadius;
      if (!mSnap) {
          cx += mPageOffset * threeRadius;
      }
      if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
          dX = longOffset + cx;
          dY = shortOffset;
      } else {
          dX = shortOffset;
          dY = longOffset + cx;
      }
      canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mPaintFill);
  }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent ev) {
      if (super.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
          return true;
      }
      if ((mViewPager == null) || (mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() == 0)) {
          return false;
      }

      final int action = ev.getAction() & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK;
      switch (action) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
          mLastMotionX = ev.getX();
          break;

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
          final int activePointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(
                  ev, mActivePointerId);
          final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, activePointerIndex);
          final float deltaX = x - mLastMotionX;

          if (!mIsDragging) {
              if (Math.abs(deltaX) > mTouchSlop) {
                  mIsDragging = true;
              }
          }

          if (mIsDragging) {
              mLastMotionX = x;
              if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging() || mViewPager.beginFakeDrag()) {
                  mViewPager.fakeDragBy(deltaX);
              }
          }

          break;
      }

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          if (!mIsDragging) {
              final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
              final int width = getWidth();
              final float halfWidth = width / 2f;
              final float sixthWidth = width / 6f;

              if ((mCurrentPage > 0) && (ev.getX() < halfWidth - sixthWidth)) {
                  if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                      mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage - 1);
                  }
                  return true;
              } else if ((mCurrentPage < count - 1)
                      && (ev.getX() > halfWidth + sixthWidth)) {
                  if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                      mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPage + 1);
                  }
                  return true;
              }
          }

          mIsDragging = false;
          mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER;
          if (mViewPager.isFakeDragging())
              mViewPager.endFakeDrag();
          break;

      case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
          final int index = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
          mLastMotionX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, index);
          mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, index);
          break;
      }

      case MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
          final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
          final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev,
                  pointerIndex);
          if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
              final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
              mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev,
                      newPointerIndex);
          }
          mLastMotionX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev,
                  MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId));
          break;
      }

      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public void setViewPager(ViewPager view) {
      if (mViewPager == view) {
          return;
      }
      if (mViewPager != null) {
          mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(null);
      }
      if (view.getAdapter() == null) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(
                  "ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
      }
      mViewPager = view;
      mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
      invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void setViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition) {
      setViewPager(view);
      setCurrentItem(initialPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
      if (mViewPager == null) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager has not been bound.");
      }
      mViewPager.setCurrentItem(item);
      mCurrentPage = item;
      invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
      invalidate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      mScrollState = state;

      if (mListener != null) {
          mListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
          int positionOffsetPixels) {
      mCurrentPage = position;
      mPageOffset = positionOffset;
      invalidate();

      if (mListener != null) {
          mListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                  positionOffsetPixels);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
      if (mSnap || mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
          mCurrentPage = position;
          mSnapPage = position;
          invalidate();
      }

      if (mListener != null) {
          mListener.onPageSelected(position);
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
      mListener = listener;
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see android.view.View#onMeasure(int, int)
   */
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
      if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
          setMeasuredDimension(measureLong(widthMeasureSpec),
                  measureShort(heightMeasureSpec));
      } else {
          setMeasuredDimension(measureShort(widthMeasureSpec),
                  measureLong(heightMeasureSpec));
      }
  }

  /**
   * Determines the width of this view
   * 
   * @param measureSpec
   *            A measureSpec packed into an int
   * @return The width of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
   */
  private int measureLong(int measureSpec) {
      int result;
      int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
      int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

      if ((specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) || (mViewPager == null)) {
          // We were told how big to be
          result = specSize;
      } else {
          // Calculate the width according the views count
          final int count = mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount();
          result = (int) (getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight()
                  + (count * 2 * mRadius) + (count - 1) * mRadius + 1);
          // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by
          // measureSpec
          if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
              result = Math.min(result, specSize);
          }
      }
      return result;
  }

  /**
   * Determines the height of this view
   * 
   * @param measureSpec
   *            A measureSpec packed into an int
   * @return The height of the view, honoring constraints from measureSpec
   */
  private int measureShort(int measureSpec) {
      int result;
      int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
      int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

      if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
          // We were told how big to be
          result = specSize;
      } else {
          // Measure the height
          result = (int) (2 * mRadius + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom() + 1);
          // Respect AT_MOST value if that was what is called for by
          // measureSpec
          if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
              result = Math.min(result, specSize);
          }
      }
      return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
      SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
      mCurrentPage = savedState.currentPage;
      mSnapPage = savedState.currentPage;
      requestLayout();
  }

  @Override
  public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
      Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
      SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
      savedState.currentPage = mCurrentPage;
      return savedState;
  }

  static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
      int currentPage;

      public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
          super(superState);
      }

      private SavedState(Parcel in) {
          super(in);
          currentPage = in.readInt();
      }

      @Override
      public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
          super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
          dest.writeInt(currentPage);
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
      public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
          @Override
          public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
              return new SavedState(in);
          }

          @Override
          public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
              return new SavedState[size];
          }
      };
  }
  ```

  }
- PageIndicator

  public interface PageIndicator extends ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
      /**
       * Bind the indicator to a ViewPager.
       *
       * @param view
       */
      void setViewPager(ViewPager view);

  ```
  /**
   * Bind the indicator to a ViewPager.
   *
   * @param view
   * @param initialPosition
   */
  void setViewPager(ViewPager view, int initialPosition);

  /**
   * <p>Set the current page of both the ViewPager and indicator.</p>
   *
   * <p>This <strong>must</strong> be used if you need to set the page before
   * the views are drawn on screen (e.g., default start page).</p>
   *
   * @param item
   */
  void setCurrentItem(int item);

  /**
   * Set a page change listener which will receive forwarded events.
   *
   * @param listener
   */
  void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener);

  /**
   * Notify the indicator that the fragment list has changed.
   */
  void notifyDataSetChanged();
  ```

  }

Comment: Can you provide Code reference. While am implementing i found more issues to apply your solution. If there is an code example (sample work) from gitup will e usefull.